# The state information is invalid Viewstate problems during aspx page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I am getting below error while any Postback events of any buttons fires.

I have load  aspx page’s  html  in home page div .

Jquery :

```
$("#ancProd1").click(function () {
        $("#prodcut1").load("/Product1List.aspx");
    });

$("#ancProd2").click(function () {
        $("#prodcut2").load("/Product2List.aspx");
    });
```

Page Design :

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id=" prodcut1">
                        </div>


  <div class="tab-pane fade" id=" prodcut2">
                        </div>
```

Aspx page contains  a server controls like repeater and hidden fields.

There is no problems in load aspx page into div . it’s look perfect.

But while I am trying to click any button of an ASPX page which are loaded in div. then below error comes .

> **The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.**

I think it’s viewstate problems . can you please help me to resolved this issue .